# errror al añadir un nuevo dato para abstraer

Tags: python, mvc, odoo

En el popup de odoo que estoy editando ya pude corregir algunos error es de búsqueda que tenia pero ahora en el diccionario que estoy poniendo para abstraer la informacion añadi un nuevo campo a abstraer pero cuando obtengo le reporte me manda un error y por lo que entiendo la traza del error pone que solo esta esperando 1 y no muchos o alg asi

Adjunto codigo:

```
import json
import io
from datetime import date
from odoo.tools import date_utils
from odoo import fields, models, api
from odoo.exceptions import UserError, ValidationError
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
class SaleReportAdvance(models.TransientModel):
_name = "sale_report_general"

from_date = fields.Date(string="Fecha de inicio")
to_date = fields.Date(string='Fecha final')
type_transport = fields.Selection(
    [('c', 'Cotizaciones'), ('a', 'Aereo'), ('m', 'Maritmo'), ('t', 'Terrestre'), ('f', 'Ferias'),
     ('i', 'Importacion')], string='Tipo de cotizacion', default='c', required=True)
seller_id = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='hr.employee', string='Ejecutivo')
country_arrival = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='res.country', string='Destino')

def _get_data(self):
    sale = self.env['sale.order'].search([('state', '!=', 'cancel')])
    validity_date = date.today()

    if self.from_date and self.to_date:
        sales_order = list(filter(lambda
                                      x: x.date_order.date() >= self.from_date and x.date_order.date() <= self.to_date,
                                  sale))
    elif not self.from_date and not self.to_date:
        sales_order = list(filter(lambda
                                      x: x.date_order.date() <= validity_date,
                                  sale))
    else:
        sales_order = sale

    result = []
    seller = []
    country = []
    for rec in self.seller_id:
        a = {
            'id': rec,
            'name': rec.name
        }
        seller.append(a)
        logger.info('**********seller*** {0}****'.format(seller))
    for rec in self.country_arrival:
        a = {
            'id': rec,
            'name': rec.name
        }
        country.append(a)
        logger.info('**********country*** {0}****'.format(country))

    logger.info('***********************Eligio ver algun tipo de cotización*************%s******' % self.type_transport)
    #busca los informes de forma generica
    if self.type_transport == 'c' and not self.seller_id and not self.country_arrival:
        for so in sales_order:
            if so.date_order:
                res = {
                    'name': so.name,
                    'date': so.date_order,
                    'partner': so.partner_id.name,
                    'consignee': so.consignee_id.name,
                    'seller': so.seller_id.name,
                    'freight': so.freight_assured,
                    'gross': so.gross_weight,
                    'volume': so.volume,
                    'assured': so.assured,
                    'custodian': so.invoice_amount,
                    'country': so.country_arrival.name,
                    'types': so.type_transport,
                    'total': so.amount_total,
                    'collect': so.total_cc
                }
                result.append(res)
                logger.info('**********result type_transport = c ***{0}****'.format(res))


data = {
        'ids': self,
        'model': 'sale_report_general',
        'form': result,
        'seller_id': seller,
        'country_arrival': country,
        'no_value': False,
        'employee': self.seller_id.name,
        'country': self.country_arrival.name,
        'from_date': self.from_date,
        'to_date': self.to_date,
        'types': self.type_transport
    }
    return data
def get_ventas_report(self):
    data = self._get_data()
    logger.info('**************Obtuvo el informe de ventas')
    return self.env.ref('sale_report_terrestre.action_general_report').report_action(self, data=data)

    if self.date_order and self.validity_date and not self.seller_id and not self.country_arrival:
        data['no_value'] = True
        return data
```

esa es la estructura del código con el cual estoy haciendo la abstracción como podria poner el campo ya que el campo que añadí al diccionario de res fue este `collect:so.total_cc` y es de ahí de ese dato que me esta mandando error revise el modelo de donde estoy abstrallendo ese datopero si esta bien tiene el mismo nombre pero por alguna razon me manda este error:

Adjunto imagen del error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ese es el error que esta mandando y no entiendo porque si esta dentro del mismo modelo de sale.order que puedo hacer en este caso para corregir ese error

Comment: El error está aquí: `'collect': so.total_cc``. En esta linea `total_cc` trae varias sale.order y al parecer `collect` solo está esperando una.

Comment: @Legna eso ya lo corregi pero sobre esa misma abstraccion estoy teniendo otro problema nose si me puedas ayudar esque estoy tratando de abstrar un monto pero me estamamndando varios errores

Comment: quiero extraer el precio unitario de este campo **'custodian':so._calc_amounts(so.product_id.name == 'CUSTODIO'),** y del modelo que lo estoy abstrayendo que es el de sale.order ahi estan guardando el precio unitario pero me esta mandaodo errores y como todo esta dentro de un def o algo asi esta algo comlicado yno se como puedo plasmarlo en esta abstraccion

Comment: Esa linea que pones no está en la pregunta.

Comment: de echo hice una pregunta nueva y es diferente

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/581363/como-abstraer-un-solo-campo-de-las-lineas-de-detalle-de-odoo es esa @Legna