# como abstraer un solo campo de las lineas de detalle de odoo

Tags: python, mvc, odoo

Estoy tratando de abstraer un campo de una linea de detalle para plasmarlo en los infomres del popup de odoo que estoy creando en este caso con el que estoy hacindo pruebas es con uno de esos detalles pero solo quiero abstraer el subtotal pero me marca un error de que solo esta esperando uno porque en si la orden en el modelo tiene 5 y yo solo necesito el subtotal de 1
adjunto codigo:

```
import json
import io
from datetime import date
from odoo.tools import date_utils
from odoo import fields, models, api
from odoo.exceptions import UserError, ValidationError
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
class SaleReportAdvance(models.TransientModel):
_name = "sale_report_general"

from_date = fields.Date(string="Fecha de inicio")
to_date = fields.Date(string='Fecha final')
type_transport = fields.Selection(
    [('c', 'Cotizaciones'), ('a', 'Aereo'), ('m', 'Maritmo'), ('t', 'Terrestre'), ('f', 'Ferias'),
     ('i', 'Importacion')], string='Tipo de cotizacion', default='c', required=True)
seller_id = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='hr.employee', string='Ejecutivo')
country_arrival = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='res.country', string='Destino')

def _get_data(self):
    sale = self.env['sale.order'].search([('state', '!=', 'cancel')])
    validity_date = date.today()

    if self.from_date and self.to_date:
        sales_order = list(filter(lambda
                                      x: x.date_order.date() >= self.from_date and x.date_order.date() <= self.to_date,
                                  sale))
    elif not self.from_date and not self.to_date:
        sales_order = list(filter(lambda
                                      x: x.date_order.date() <= validity_date,
                                  sale))
    else:
        sales_order = sale

    result = []
    seller = []
    country = []
    for rec in self.seller_id:
        a = {
            'id': rec,
            'name': rec.name
        }
        seller.append(a)
        logger.info('**********seller*** {0}****'.format(seller))
    for rec in self.country_arrival:
        a = {
            'id': rec,
            'name': rec.name
        }
        country.append(a)
        logger.info('**********country*** {0}****'.format(country))

    logger.info('***********************Eligio ver algun tipo de cotización*************%s******' % self.type_transport)
    #busca los informes de forma generica
    if self.type_transport == 'c' and not self.seller_id and not self.country_arrival:
        for so in sales_order:
            if so.date_order:
                res = {
                    'name': so.name,
                    'date': so.date_order,
                    'partner': so.partner_id.name,
                    'consignee': so.consignee_id.name,
                    'seller': so.seller_id.name,
                    'freight': so.freight_assured,
                    'gross': so.gross_weight,
                    'volume': so.volume,
                    'assured': so.assured,
                    'custodian': so.order_line.price_subtotal,
                    'custom': so.invoice_amount,
                    'country': so.country_arrival.name,
                    'types': so.type_transport,
                    'total': so.amount_total,
                }
                result.append(res)
                logger.info('**********result type_transport = c ***{0}****'.format(res))

data = {
        'ids': self,
        'model': 'sale_report_general',
        'form': result,
        'seller_id': seller,
        'country_arrival': country,
        'no_value': False,
        'employee': self.seller_id.name,
        'country': self.country_arrival.name,
        'from_date': self.from_date,
        'to_date': self.to_date,
        'types': self.type_transport
    }
    return data
def get_ventas_report(self):
    data = self._get_data()
    logger.info('**************Obtuvo el informe de ventas')
    return self.env.ref('sale_report_terrestre.action_general_report').report_action(self, data=data)

    if self.date_order and self.validity_date and not self.seller_id and not self.country_arrival:
        data['no_value'] = True
        return data
```

asi es como tengo el filtro al parecer todos los campos que abstraigo estan ien a excepcion de este `'custodian': so.order_line.price_subtotal,` me pone en el error que hay vaios y solo esta esperando 1 que puedo hacer para corregir esos

Adjunto imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
exactamente quiero extraer el subtotal del ultimo campo pero como podria ponerlo en el array de res para que lo abstraiga y no mande este error

Adjutno imagen del error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que puedo hacer o ocmo le puedo especificar que solo abstraiga el subtotal de ese ultimo detalle y no el de todos

esto me aparece cuando se ejecuta el logger

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la parte custodian aparecen todos los subtotales de los productos adicionales en este caso yo solo quiero extraer 1 que es el de custodio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los campos `many2One` y `many2Many` se pueden manejar como listas. Si quieres obtener el último valor de los agregados puedes hacer uso de `so.order_line.mapped('price_subtotal')[-1]`

Comment: ok lo intentare asi

Comment: mando este error

Comment: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo14.0/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo14.0/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Lgna segui intentando pero dice que el list index esta fuera

Comment: Pon un print para ver que te trae `so.order_line.mapped('price_subtotal')`

Comment: la funcion tiene un logger y si trae los subtotales

Comment: Puedes actualizar tu pregunta con el log que te aparece?

Comment: sip dame un segundo

Comment: Listo @Legna es la ultima imagen

Comment: No actualizaste el código que modificaste.